How to notify Angular of string input changes for an external JS library?
My component receives an HTML string input, which is passed to another JavaScript library responsible for building the DOM and performing its operations. Each time the input changes, the JavaScript library should be invoked, independently of Angular. This component acts as a "host" for the library.
When I pass a string content, the JavaScript library builds the DOM. Outside the component, there is a "revert" button that, when clicked, fetches the original HTML string from the server.
The issue arises because Angular doesn't detect changes to the string value unless it actually changes, and ngOnChanges is not triggered. One option is to use ViewChild to get the component and directly invoke a method like refresh, but I prefer not to do that. I want it to respond to input changes.
I prefer not to pass an object instead of a string as it feels like a workaround.
Based on these facts, what are the ways to notify Angular that the input has changed?
Here is an example code:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
console.clear();

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'foo',
  template: ` im foo `,
})
export class Foo {
  @Input() set data(value: string) {
    console.log({ value });
    // new jsDomManipulation(this.elementRef...)
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('changed');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [Foo],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>

    <foo [data]="data"></foo>

    <button (click)="toggle()">click</button>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';

  data: any = null;

  server = { data: 'some' }

  toggle() {
    this.data = this.server.data; //fake call to the server to get the same string content..
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);


Is that javascript library opensource? Could we at least have its name? The main problem for change detection is that it works the opposite as you think. It checks the components values to change the HTML. Now you are expecting it to check the HTML to change the components, which does not work. Your best bet would be to hook into the library's events somehow. Your idea of using ViewChild is good, but if you do not want to do that... Please provide a minimum reproduction so we can fiddle with it.

If you send the same value, Angular don't execute the ngChanges
this.data = {...this.server.data}; //<--this send a new value
this.data = this.server.data //<--do nothing

BTW, can you call directly the javascript library? can you simply create a custom event and listen in your javascript this event?

angular checks by the value of variable

Have you tried calling ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges() after the value changed from another source.
refer Triggering change detection manually in Angular

angular checks by the value of variable.
